# Como utilizar o push em state no React Native?

Tags: react-native, redux

Olá

Eu estou tentando utilizar o **PUSH** no **STATE**, o push adiciona corretamente os valores, mas eu recebo este erro. Eu sei que nao pode alterar o **STATE** diretamente, mas eu estou fazendo o **SPREAD**, mas mesmo assim esta dando erro, porque ?

**Erro**

```
Error: [Immer] An immer producer returned a new value *and* modified its draft. Either return a new value *or* modify the draft., js engine: hermes
```

**Código**

```
initialState : [
    {
        name : 'A'
    },
],

add : (state, action) => [
        ...state,
        state.push(
            {
                name : 'B'
            }
        ),
        console.log(`${state}`)
    ]
```